# Obtain one single growth curve from various replicates in a growth experiment

Tags: r, standardization, fitting, growth-model, feature-scaling

I am performing a yeast growth experiment measuring areas of growth across a time interval, therefore having area (%) as my dependent variable and time (min) as my independent variable. I have three experimental conditions: Control, Treatment 1, and Treatment 2, and 3 replicates for each condition.

As my initial area percentage (t=0) is slightly different for each replicate of my conditions (e.g. replicate1-control: 5%, replicate2-control: 6.5%, replicate3-control: 10%), I would like to perform some kind of standardization so there is a unique growth curve for each condition before fitting them to one of the models (logistic, Gompertz, Richards, etc.), and calculating the growth rate and duplication time. Given this, I have the following questions:

- Is there any method to reliably perform this standardization?
- Which method could be the most reliable?

[image: Example of the data, A is the area percentage]

[image: An example of how the graph for two replicates of the same condition looks]

I have read some articles and documentation of R packages about this topic, but most of them only offer examples of the data fitting of different conditions. They don't offer details or they are unclear about whether there is a previous standardization step before fitting the data. I am not sure if the functions fitting the models perform some kind of standardization before the fitting, and if so, I couldn't find which is the method or formula through which it is performed.

Example data could be find in this repository: [Preliminar data](https://github.com/alvaljan/Example-data-for-experiments)

Comment: You may try applying a nonlinear mixed effects model. If you share at least a portion of your data I may give it a try.

Comment: That orange line can't be modelled with a simple growth model. The model would need to take into account whatever caused the drop to zero at time 500 and the later regrowth (possibly of a different micro-organism?).

Comment: @utobi Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the late reply. That sounds like a very interesting approach to solve my problem, but I am not sure about how to do it. Of course you can have a portion of my data, you can find it in the edited question, at the end of it. Let me know if you can access and download it.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your answer. In the case of the published image, it is just an example of the data I want to model. In fact, what I want to do after obtaining one single curve is to separate it in three "growth intervals" and each interval would be modelled or fitted to different yeast growth models. That drop you are mentioning is mainly caused by the growth conditions that we are studying and we will address them in our analysis.

Answer (score 1):

See Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long) for extensive explanation of how to model longitudinal data like growth curves. Instead of first reducing the replicates for each treatment to a single growth curve, you model the association of outcome with time flexibly as a function of treatment condition while taking into account the correlations among the values found within each replicate. In that case, including the initial value as a *predictor* in the model is a way to handle the differences among starting conditions. How well that will work depends on the details of your data. If all area values are greater than 0, you might consider working with log-transformed areas.

From what you show in the figure, I'd recommend against a simple parametric growth curve model (e.g., logistic). That's particularly the case if growth conditions can change during the experiment, as you imply in a comment to explain the dip in the orange curve at about a time of 500. Flexible fitting of time as a predictor without imposing a particular parametric form, as with a regression spline, would seem to be preferable. That would still allow you to discern differences among treatments and might also make it easier to handle the 3 "growth intervals" that you mention in a comment (depending on how those intervals are defined).

Comment: Hello, @EdM. Thanks for your answer. I am not clear what do you refer about when suggesting to model the association of outcome with time flexibly as a function of treatment condition. If you could please explain me this a bit more, that would be amazing.
As all my area values are greater than 0, I have other question, and it is: working with log-transformed areas will not shape differently my data?

Comment: @PaoloVallejoJaneta a regression spline can give flexible modeling of time, as explained in Chapter 2 of the Harrell reference linked above. You include an interaction between the spline and the treatments to allow the trajectory over time to differ depending on treatment. The choice between using raw areas and log-transformed values depends in part on how measurement errors are related to observed values. If errors are fairly constant over the range of measurements, then raw values are OK. If they are approximately proportional to measured values, log transformation can be better.

Answer (score 1):

Imo, you don't need to standardize or normalize your data.

The preliminary data matrix can be reshaped to better enable growth curve models.

For example, stack up the three conditions into a matrix with single fields for TIME, AREA and CELL. Then add a CELL TYPE field coded 1, 2, 3 or add three dummy variables, one for each cell type. Build the growth models on that data.

[image]

And so on...

Comment: Thanks @Mike Hunter for your answer. In my data there are no different cell types, what I have are multiple replicates for different treatment conditions (e. different chemical concentrations). Still, I could include 2 variables: one for number of replicate and another for the treatment condition.
What makes me doubt about this approach is the fact that when working with R libraries to fit a data frame like this, most of them takes the average value (for each timepoint) of all the replicates from the same condition, so I'm not sure if taking the average without previous analysis is accurate.

Comment: I don't know R, so I can't suggest an appropriate module. Given the above data matrix ways to think about this analysis include, first, as an ANOVA and then as a pooled time series or panel data model.